# Is it possible to automate Extrude in Blender?

Tags: python, extrude

I'm a beginner Blender user and I've been extruding some logos, but as time went on, they've become too many logos for me to extrude them by hand. I wonder if it is possible to extrude them automatically, probably by the use of coding (python maybe?). Does anyone have an answer to this task?

Comment: Can you post screenshots of what you're doing/what you want to accomplish? This question is a bit unclear at the moment.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/34mdF7JKdZLO Usually I just import the SVG file and extrude it in the Curve properties, geometry tab. What I want to do is to automate that in some way, as the process is always the same.

Answer (score 2):

This script should do the trick:

```
import bpy 
from pathlib import Path

root = Path("/your/folder/with/svgs-in-it/")

for file in root.glob('*.svg'):
    fp = str(file.resolve())
    bpy.ops.import_curve.svg(filepath=fp)
    
for curve in bpy.data.curves[:]:
    curve.extrude = .001 # the thickness that you want
```

Comment: I ran the code into Blender and it did nothing. Probably because I've never used Scripting before. You just need to copy and paste the script and that's it or am I missing something?

Comment: I can't put the file path where all of your svgs in my script. I don't know where that is on your computer. That's why my script says "/your/folder/with/svgs-in-it/".